# Notice: Undefined offset: 0 using Array in PHP

Tags: php, arrays

When I'm executing this code-

```
public $speaker_list=array();

for($i=0;$i<$nbre_speaker;$i++)
{
     $speaker_list[$i]=new Speaker($_POST['speaker'+$i],$_POST['pro_speaker'+$i],$_POST['bio_speaker'+$i]);
}
```

I'm getting the error:

> Notice: Undefined offset: 0
>
> Notice: Undefined offset: 1

Comment: That code is neither valid nor complete.

Comment: @Faery: There is never reason to use `array_push`, except in very specific (and rare) circumstances.

Comment: string concatenation -> `'speaker'.$i`

Comment: the problem is in this line :

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming `$nbre_speaker` is set to something sensible outside the code you provided.

Try this

```
public $speaker_list = array();

for($i=0; $i < $nbre_speaker; $i++)
{
     if ( isset($_POST['speaker'.$i], $_POST['pro_speaker'.$i], $_POST['bio_speaker'.$i] )) {
         $speaker_list[$i] = new Speaker($_POST['speaker'.$i], 
                                         $_POST['pro_speaker'.$i], 
                                         $_POST['bio_speaker'.$i]);
     } else {
        // report error, or do something to fix it.
     }

}
```